# Translate DllImport from static member of static class in C# console app to member of C++ CLR console app

Tags: c#, c++-cli, translation, dllimport, static-classes

I have the following and I can't shift the error surrounding the DllImport

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <msclr/auto_gcroot.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Diagnostics;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
using namespace System::Threading;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace System::Text;

namespace WinFlix
{
    class FlickWin
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        extern "C" bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

I've been tranlating this class from C# where it was a `static` class, which is not available in C++.NET. My new C++ project is of type "CLR Console Application".

I get

> error C2059: syntax error : 'string'

and

> error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

both referring to that 'extern "C"' line.

I've searched my previous work and while I am competent with C++/CLI I've not had to call down into WinAPI functions like this before. Those two errors are all that are beating me :-/

TBH, this thing exhausted my patience and I deleted it, could go back and re-create it but I preferred fixing my C# instead. Help appreciated for future reference though.

Comment: I'm not using PInvoke as I'm still new to C# and keeping it 'simple'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<strike>The extern "C" is inappropriate for DllImport. That's the source of the error.</strike>

The problem is that you are declaring your P/invoke inside a class. As far as I can tell, in C++ they are meant to be declared as free functions outside any classes. I've not found much documentation for P/invoke from C++/CLI, probably because P/invoke is not needed from C++/CLI.

You don't need P/invoke with C++/CLI because the compiler can include standard C++ header files and link against native libraries. Just include windows.h and call the Win32 APIs with no futher effort. That's one of the best points of C++/CLI.

Comment: I'm using your advice in another project now, "Just include windows.h". Tried that, because my function was flagged "declared but not defined". Now up pop 37 other errors, mostly ambiguities, the first being representative is, "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\include\objidl.h(6143) : error C2872: 'IDataObject' : ambiguous symbol"

Comment: Fixed last error, the MSDN example was misleading me to use 'static bool DestroyIcon' when I needed 'extern bool DestroyIcon'

Comment: What I said before, MS were right, in some cases, the original app, as above, is a console /CLR app. Now I'm getting 'extern' is illegal on members. But I can whip it outside and make it extern again, even "extern "C"", FWIW! So you got my vote but I think you may be wrong, as the example with "extern "C"" came also from MSDN and is now working as well as any other. More concerned with why my main() can't be run from inside of the class and use its static members now though.

Comment: @John Yes you are right. The issue is using P/invoke for a class member. I should have spotted that. You can't make it a static member and an extern since only one storage class specifier can be used. Hence you need to declare the P/invoke as a free function. But if you are going to use C++/CLI you should take advantage of it's great feature of being able to call native libraries without arduous P/invoke!

Answer (score 1):

This is correct C++/CLI function definition:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]         
static int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

Agree with David Heffernan, there is no point to use PInvoke in C++/CLI - just call API directly. PInvoke is for C#/VB .NET developers.